# getting an error while run sql query using IF condition

Tags: sql, mariadb

Getting an error when i run the query

```
INSERT INTO `received_order`(
    `retailer_name`,
    `order_id`,
    `dboy_username`,
    `product_id`,
    `quantity`,
    `create_date`,
    `timestamp`,
    `payment_status`,
    `delivery_status`,
    `device_type`
)
VALUES(
    'ankur',
    'OD123',
    'manish',
    'PIDEAB565',
    (
    SELECT
        `product_quantity` IF(product_quantity > 50, 50, 0)
    FROM
        `master_stock`
    WHERE
        `product_id` = 'PIDEAB565'
),
'',
'',
'',
'',
''
)
```

> MySQL said:
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF(product_quantity
>   50, 50, 0)
>       FROM
>           `master_stock`
>       WHERE
>   ' at line 20

Comment: Are you trying to return one or two columns?

Comment: What's the first ``product_quantity`` for? I also would write this as a `insert into .. select` and have the strings in the `select`.

Comment: `SELECT IF(product_quantity > 50, 50, 0) as product_quantity FROM`

Comment: @user3783243 sir, product quantity is 20

Comment: Your `SELECT column_name function(blah)` construct doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line `product_quantity IF(product_quantity > 50, 50, 0)` IF can not be used like this. You should use `case` statement instead.

Try This

```
INSERT INTO `received_order`(
    `retailer_name`,
    `order_id`,
    `dboy_username`,
    `product_id`,
    `quantity`,
    `create_date`,
    `timestamp`,
    `payment_status`,
    `delivery_status`,
    `device_type`
)
VALUES(
    'ankur',
    'OD123',
    'manish',
    'PIDEAB565',
    (
    SELECT
        case when `product_quantity`>50 then 50 else 0 end
    FROM
        `master_stock`
    WHERE
        `product_id` = 'PIDEAB565'
),
'',
'',
'',
'',
''
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. very help full

Comment: This works because you've inadvertently fixed the syntax error (that bogus `product_quantity`) but the explanation given is incorrect. There's nothing wrong with using `IF()` here.